# 8bit to 16bit conversion

Tags: c, image

I have an image which captures 8 bit. I'm looking to convert the 8 bit values to 16 bit. I used the following

```
short temp16 =  (short)val[i] << 8 ;
```

where `val` is an  array of 8 bit samples.

The above statement makes noisy. 
Can anybody suggest a method for 8bit to 16bit conversion?

Comment: noisy as in the image is still there, but is now noisy?  Or noisy as in the image now looks like noise?

Comment: It looks like C, but just to be sure - please add a tag indicating the language.  There are a lot of C-like languages out there.

Comment: noisy after sampling, colorformat Y8 (gray scale, unsigned)

Comment: A pure 8-bit to 16-bit conversion will not affect the noise at all. Perhaps you are looking for a noise reducing image processing method? There are some but all will remove some detail or sharpness.

Comment: ops my fault in LUT. thanks all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure bitshifting won't give you pure white. 0xff << 8 == 0xff00, not 0xffff as expected.

One trick is to use val[i] << 8 + val[i] and remember proper datatypes (size, signedness). That way you get 0x00 -> 0x0000 and 0xff -> 0xffff.

Comment: That's not a "trick", it's the proper way how to map range (0..255) to (0..65535).

The factor between both ranges is 65535 / 255 = 257 (ratio between ends or both ranges) and 257 = (256 + 1) so instead of multiplying by 257, which is kinda ugly number, you can mutliply the value by 256 (i.e. left shift by 8 bits) and add once more.

Answer (score 4):

Is val[] signed or unsigned 8bit?  Cast it to unsigned (assuming you've got the usual convention of 0=darkest, 255=brightest) then cast it to signed short (I assume that's what you want, since plain 'short' is by default signed).

Comment: Definitely need to be precise about signedness when you're dealing with bits.

Answer (score 0):

A good example is given there: [Converting two uint8_t words into one of uint16_t and one of uint16_t into two of uint8_t](http://www.badprog.com/c-type-converting-two-uint8-t-words-into-one-of-uint16-t-and-one-of-uint16-t-into-two-of-uint8-t).