# Scale integral types to a different bits size

Tags: c++, c++17

How to scale up/down integral types to other sizes, example from 8 bits to 16 bits should be:

- 0x00 -> 0x0000
- 0xFF -> 0xFFFF

This is what I came up with so far as a generic solution. Scale down works fine, but scale up only works if the size of the return type is two times larger than input type, 8 to 16, or 16 to 32, but not 8 to 32.

I don't know what other uses of such a function would be, other than 8 bits to 16 and vice versa. I am just tinkering with this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <math.h>


template<class PxOut, class PxIn,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<PxOut>::value, PxOut>::type , /// Must be integral
         typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<PxIn>::value, PxIn>::type,
         typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_signed<PxOut>::value, PxOut>::type , /// Must be positive
         typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_signed<PxIn>::value, PxOut>::type
         >

static inline constexpr PxOut binScale(PxIn x)
{

    if constexpr ( std::is_same<PxOut,PxIn>::value ){
        return x;
    }

    else if constexpr ( (/*2**/sizeof( PxIn ) ) < sizeof( PxOut ) ){
        /// ## Scale Up
        /// ## https://stackoverflow.com/a/6436100/12209845
        ///
        PxOut xx = PxIn( x );
        const uint8_t sft = sizeof( PxIn ) * 8;
        return ( ( xx + ( xx << sft ) ) << sft ) + std::numeric_limits<PxIn>::max();
    }
    else if constexpr ( sizeof( PxIn ) > sizeof( PxOut ) ){
        /// ## Scale Down
        /// ## https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/gui/painting/qrgba64.h.html#_ZN7QRgba647div_257Et
        ///
        const uint8_t sft = ( sizeof( PxIn ) * 8 ) - sizeof(PxOut) * 8;
        return ( x - ( x >> sft ) ) >> sft;
    }
}
/// Change the types and the test value in the next lines
///
using PxIn = uint8_t;
using PxOut =  uint16_t;
const PxIn dv = 2;


int main(int , char *[])
{
    std::cout << (uint64_t)binScale<PxOut,PxIn>(
                    (std::numeric_limits<PxIn>::max() ) /
                    dv );

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << (uint64_t)std::numeric_limits<PxOut>::max() / dv ;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

The scale should be done in terms of percentages from the max value of the return type.
8 bits to 16 bits, would look something like:

```
/*
8 bits       :  16 bits
255 -> 65535 :  Scale to 1/1 of 65535 or (0xFFFF)
127 -> 32767 :  Scale to 1/2 of 65535 or (0xFFFF)
85  -> 22015 :  Scale to 1/3 of 65535 or (0xFFFF)
63  -> 16383 :  Scale to 1/4 of 65535 or (0xFFFF)
0   -> 0     :  Scale to 0% of 65535 or (0xFFFF)
*/
```

Say you have an 8 bits image, and you want to scale each pixel to 16 bits, so that it changes from 0xFF -> 0xFFFF, that's one particular use I can think of.

Comment: Do you have a question also?

Comment: Yes, my question is how to fix the "Scale Up" part.

Comment: I do not understand. How would `0xab` "scale up"? to `0xabab`? How would 8 to 32 bits scale up? To `0xabababab`? What are the rules or what formula is used to "scaling up" and "scaling down"? I do not think giving two examples for `0x00` and `0xFF` is sufficient - could you give more examples? And why doesn't `0xff` "scale up" to `0x00ff`?

Comment: @KamilCuk There is a link https://stackoverflow.com/a/6436100/12209845 mentioned in the exposed source code which helps to understand OPs issue. After having tinkered myself with my (beloved) Windows 7 calculator, I saw something like a scheme: 0xff => 0xffff: 65535 = 255 * 257. 257 = 256 + 1. Hence, I enjoyed to see the accepted answer where it was a << 8 + a (what's actually the same). ;-)

Comment: A hint after thinking a bit about your question: Scale 8 bits up to 16: a << 8 + a. Scale 16 bits down to 8: a >> 8. It might be surprising that this looks somehow "asymmetrically". However, this is integral arithmetic. There is nothing to subtract in the 2nd case because the part to subtract is shifted out (less than 1) and irrelevant.

Comment: @KamilCuk I added an edit, to clarify the question

Comment: What about the easiest solution: convert to `double` (from 0 to 1), multiply by the max value of the output range.

Comment: I found a simple stupid solution (I believe): [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e61f9fa756cf12b) which works at least for 8 -> 16, 8 -> 24, 8 -> 32. The result of 8 -> 28 was not satisfying as well as 8 -> 25. (That might be tolerable. Who cares of 25 bit numbers?)

Comment: Oops. I was not aware that I'm not the only one who likes to define `uint`. [**Fixed Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4cdf60b57f1232f) where I tested conversion to 64 bit.

Comment: @Scheff, this is not quite it, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b6d9aa2ee5cae68

Comment: If believe you made a logical mistake. (That's the trickiness of integral math.) 0x7f is not the half of 0xff / 2 -> it's below (though it's the correct result for _integral_ division). 0x80 is not the half of 0xff / 2 -> it's above. So, 0x7f cannot scale up to 0x7fff or 0x7fffffff or 0x7fffffffffff.

Comment: @Scheff, My bad, This is becoming so confusing, I think I need a time out to think about this, and life as a whole :)

Comment: Maybe, this example helps: scale-up the decimal range [0, 9] to the range [0, 99]. The scale factor would be 11. But 4 (= 9 / 2) would scale up to 44 (but not 49 as you might have expected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible application of what OP tries to perform is the scaling of colors from a lower pixel depth (say 8 bits per pixel) to a higher pixel depth (say 16 bits per pixel).

At the first glance, you may think the factor has to be 2<sup>16</sup> / 2<sup>8</sup> = 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 but that's wrong.

It would not map 0xff (white with 8 bit) to 0xff00 where white in 16 bit would be 0xffff.

Instead, the factor has to be 0xffff / 0xff = 0x101 = 257.

This is where I based my sample implementation on:

```
using uintN = unsigned long long;

constexpr uintN getMax(uintN nBits)
{
  assert(nBits <= sizeof (uintN) * 8);
  return (uintN)-1 >> (sizeof (uintN) * 8 - nBits);
}
```

and the scale-up factor becomes then:

```
uintN f = getMax(to) / getMax(from);
```

where `to` and `from` are the respective number of bits.

Amazingly, the factor is always an integral value for all possible pairs for `from` and `to` of 8, 16, 32, 64 (with `from` ≤ `to`).

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using uintN = unsigned long long;

constexpr uintN getMax(uintN nBits)
{
  assert(nBits <= sizeof (uintN) * 8);
  return (uintN)-1 >> (sizeof (uintN) * 8 - nBits);
}

int main()
{
  uintN nBits[] = { 8, 16, 32, 64 };
  uintN tests[][3] = {
    { 0x7f, 0x7f7f, 0x7f7f7f7f },
    { 0xab, 0xabab, 0xabababab },
    { 0xff, 0xffff, 0xffffffff }
  };
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    uintN from = nBits[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 4; ++j) {
      uintN to = nBits[j];
      uintN f = getMax(to) / getMax(from);
      std::cout << std::dec << "from " << from << " bits to " << to << " bits: factor: " << std::hex << f << "\n";
      std::cout << "Samples:\n";
      for (auto test : tests) {
        std::cout << test[i] << " -> " << f * test[i] << '\n';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
from 8 bits to 16 bits: factor: 101
Samples:
7f -> 7f7f
ab -> abab
ff -> ffff
from 8 bits to 32 bits: factor: 1010101
Samples:
7f -> 7f7f7f7f
ab -> abababab
ff -> ffffffff
from 8 bits to 64 bits: factor: 101010101010101
Samples:
7f -> 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
ab -> abababababababab
ff -> ffffffffffffffff
from 16 bits to 32 bits: factor: 10001
Samples:
7f7f -> 7f7f7f7f
abab -> abababab
ffff -> ffffffff
from 16 bits to 64 bits: factor: 1000100010001
Samples:
7f7f -> 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
abab -> abababababababab
ffff -> ffffffffffffffff
from 32 bits to 64 bits: factor: 100000001
Samples:
7f7f7f7f -> 7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
abababab -> abababababababab
ffffffff -> ffffffffffffffff
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3377bb5f32e36310)

Answer (score 1):

When scaling up an **m** bit int to an **n** bit int (unsigned only) you will have to multiply  it by a factor of (2^n-1)/ (2^m-1 ) since we want each number to have equal spacing between them. The expression you are using is a simplification of the above expression when n=2m , suppose 2^m is a then the (2^n-1)/ (2^m-1) becomes (a^2 -1)/a-1  which is a + 1.In your case multiplication by a+1 i.e 2^8 +1 is being achieved by first shifting by 8 and then adding the original (From the stack overflow link you posted). thus when scaling from 8 to 16 or 16 to 32 it works . For 8 to 32 the expression would become a^3 +a^2 +a + 1. but I would recommend making a list of all possible combinations  you can do for scaling once (8->16,16->32,32->64,8->32,16->64,8->64) and storing the scaling factor in an array instead recomputing factors for every pixel and multiply with the scaling factor depending on in and out size.